# showing only the year portion of a date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to change the date field in my sql view so that the date will show only the year.

For example, my date field is the typical '07/01/2011'. I want to be able to have the field that changes only to the year, then another one for month, etc.

Ive tried using   `CONVERT (VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101)`, but that only shows the current date plus the format (101) isn't right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the YEAR function:

```
SELECT     OrderID, YEAR(OrderDate) AS Date
FROM         dbo.Orders
```

Comment: Good. And the MONTH and DAY functions for the other components of the date.

Comment: Yes :).  But you asked only about the year part of the Date value :)

Comment: Read the question... ", then another one for month, etc."

Comment: oops, I missed it :(.  Sorry.  All last nights I sleep for approx 4-5 hours :(.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [YEAR function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186313.aspx)?

There is also [MONTH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176052.aspx) however you may want [DATENAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395.aspx) to give `July` not `7`

This is for SQL Server but every RDBMS has these or similar

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server, you can use `datepart` to extract portions of a date:

```
SELECT datepart(yyyy, getdate())
```

See the [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) for more information.

Comment: When I do that I get a NULL in SQL.

Comment: Are you concatenating it with part of a string?  As far as I was aware, it's not possible to get NULL using `datepart` and `getdate`

Answer (score 1):

If it's T-SQL you're talking about, you can do `DATEPART(year, GETDATE())`