# how to extract only the year from the date in sql server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, datetime, extract

In sql server 2008, how to extract only the year from the date.
In DB I have a column for date, from that I need to extract the year.
Is there any function for that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [showing only the year portion of a date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6628942/showing-only-the-year-portion-of-a-date)

Answer (score 128, accepted):

```
year(@date)
year(getdate())
year('20120101')

update table
set column = year(date_column)
whre ....
```

or if you need it in another table

```
 update t
   set column = year(t1.date_column)
     from table_source t1
     join table_target t on (join condition)
    where ....
```

Comment: Here I dont want for current datetime.  I already have a column for datetime.  How to have a query to extract that?

Comment: This works; how can I store this year in another column in the table? Better to have a single line query.

Comment: Can you please explain about the following error: Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.

Comment: I guess you are trying to cast a string to a date. And the server cannot convert it to datetime type because it does not support the format.

Answer (score 17):

```
select year(current_timestamp)
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/1188)

Answer (score 14):

You can use `year()` function in sql to get the  year from the specified date.

Syntax:

```
YEAR ( date )
```

For more information [check here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186313.aspx)

Comment: Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.  Cant understand what is it? This is the error I got?

Comment: got it, it was assigned as int.

Answer (score 5):

```
year(table_column)
```

Example:

```
select * from mytable where year(transaction_day)='2013'
```

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server Script

```
declare @iDate datetime
set @iDate=GETDATE()

print year(@iDate) -- for Year

print month(@iDate) -- for Month

print day(@iDate) -- for Day
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use

SELECT DATEPART(YEAR, SomeDateColumn)

It will return the portion of a DATETIME type that corresponds to the option you specify. SO DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()) would return the current year.

Can pass other time formatters instead of YEAR like

- DAY
- MONTH
- SECOND
- MILLISECOND
- ...etc.

Answer (score 1):

the year function dose, like this:

`select year(date_column) from table_name`

Comment: There already 6+ year old answers that say this (with more details). When answering old questions, make sure your answer offers a substantially different or better quality answer than the existing answers.

Answer (score 0):

[DATEPART](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx)(yyyy, date_column) could be used to extract year. In general, DATEPART function is used to extract specific portions of a date value.

Answer (score 0):

```
---Lalmuni Demos---
create table Users
(
userid int,date_of_birth date
)
insert into Users values(4,'9/10/1991')

select DATEDIFF(year,date_of_birth, getdate()) - (CASE WHEN (DATEADD(year, DATEDIFF(year,date_of_birth, getdate()),date_of_birth)) > getdate() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Years, 
MONTH(getdate() - (DATEADD(year, DATEDIFF(year, date_of_birth, getdate()), date_of_birth))) - 1 as Months, 
DAY(getdate() - (DATEADD(year, DATEDIFF(year,date_of_birth, getdate()), date_of_birth))) - 1 as Days,
from users
```