# Enter only Year in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to enter date only in year format if I use short as datatype it's still a waste of data. I hope there must be some function or something to achieve this.

Comment: Provide the sample input and output

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12436743/how-to-extract-only-the-year-from-the-date-in-sql-server-2008

Comment: As per Mike above and store as Short type in SQL only 2 bytes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use smallint (Short). Size your data type properly, a two byte int is a better choice. By storing 4 digit years in 4 bytes, you are wasting more resources than just disk space.

For extracting year only use

```
YEAR(Date) function
```