# convert yyyy mm-dd to yyyy in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have date column in table (documentyear).
It has format  yyyy-mm-dd .
For example `2017-11-17`. How can i get `only` year?
i.e. convert from `2017-11-17 to  2017`

Comment: Hint : `Year()` or `datepart(year, col)`.

Comment: Try - `LEFT(colname,4)`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Are you saying that you are storing the date as a string? Why? You should store it as a `DATE`. A `DATE` has no format. You can use date functions on a `DATE` column to format it or extract parts, like with `YEAR(mydate)`.

Comment: Nitpicking: A `date` data type  column doesn't have a *format*.

Comment: [Try this link. This should satisfy your current task.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12436743/how-to-extract-only-the-year-from-the-date-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: if it is a string , then make it into an ISO date format by removing the hyphens, then cast to date, then apply year select year(CAST(REPLACE(YourField,'-','') as datetime2))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming it is a date, you can do:

```
select year(documentyear)             -- for an integer
select datename(year, documentyear)   -- for a string
```

Comment: how can i update table? i.e. that all table will be updated by this condition year(documentyear)

Comment: @G-spot . . . This question is about extracting the year.  If you have another question about updating, that would be quite different.

Answer (score 4):

Try this: Year function will give you value of year

```
select year('2017-11-17')
```

Answer (score 1):

you need year function of mssql server

```
     year（'2018-05-12'）
    it will return 2018
```